# Ant Design select inside form loop array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have array of product properties like that

```
[
  {
    name: 'Color',
    options: ['Blue', 'Green', 'White'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Size',
    options: ['X', 'L', 'XL'],
  }
]
```

And I trying show it in select like that

```
<Form.List name="properties">
  {properties =>
    properties.map(property => {
      // options: Array(3)
      //   0: "Blue"
      //   1: "Green"
      //   2: "White"
      // _id: "5e71f09d6fa4bb28ee5a87e4"
      // name: "Color"

      return (
        <Form.Item {...property.options}>
          <Select name={property.name}>
            <Option />
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
      );
    })
  }
</Form.List>
```

But I get an empty Select without any values :( Can somebody help me with that please?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a function with `{properties => ...}` which is never called. So just render `properties.map(...)` as a children directly e.g.:

```
<Form.List name="properties">
  {
    properties.map(property => {
      return (
        <Form.Item {...property.options}>
          <Select name={property.name}>
            <Option />
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
      );
    }
  }
</Form.List>
```

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

You need map the `options` in [`Select`](https://ant.design/components/select/):

```
options.map((option) => <Select.Option key={option} value={option}>{option}</Select.Option>);
```

```
<Form.List name="properties">
  {properties.map(({ options, name, id }) => {
      // options: Array(3)
      //   0: "Blue"
      //   1: "Green"
      //   2: "White"
      // _id: "5e71f09d6fa4bb28ee5a87e4"
      // name: "Color"

      return (
        <Form.Item key={id} name={name}>
          <Select>
            {options.map((option) => (
              <Select.Option key={option} value={option}>{option}</Select.Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
      );
    })
  }
</Form.List>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Options undefined.

Comment: Can't guess without producible example, and you shouldn't map `Options` there is not such entity here

Comment: Sure. Can you tell me please where I can make example? I mean which service I need use for it?

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();
    
<Form.Item key={id} name={name}>
              <Select
                  onChange={value=>{setValue(option)}}
                  value={option}
                 >
                {options.map((option) => (
                  <Select.Option key={option} value={option}>{option}</Select.Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Form.Item>
```